# Adicionar elementos a uma lista dentro de uma list compreension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho seguinte código:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = []
test = [result.append(i) for i in myList]
```

Cujo o output de `test` é:

> [None, None, None, None, None]

Gostaria de saber o porquê, visto que por ex se:

```
test = [print(i) for i in myList]
```

Imprime cada um com sucesso

Eu não quero a solução para isto, eu sei num ciclo for normal isto resulta, gostaria só de saber o porquê do `append` não ser executado como quero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque você está adicionando na compreension o retorno da função 'append' e a função retorna None. Exemplo:

```
>>> print(result.append(i))
None
```

Mas a variável 'result' recebeu os valores 'appendados':

```
>>> print(result)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada nesse código, acredito que ele resolve sua dúvida. :)

```
data = ['3', '7.4', '8.2']

new_data = [float(n) for n in data]

new_data

[3.0, 7.4, 8.2]
```